# Get bitmap width and height without loading to memory

Tags: android, bitmap

Im a newbie in android, So i would like to know is there any way to get the dimensions of a Bitmap without loading the bitmap into memory.??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set the BitmapFactory.Options with inJustDecodeBounds to get the image width and height without loading the bitmap pixel in memory

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
int imageWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
int imageHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;
inputStream.close();
```

For more details:

> public boolean inJustDecodeBounds
>
> Since: API Level 1 If set to true,
>   the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out... fields will
>   still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having
>   to allocate the memory for its pixels.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds

Comment: Doesn't works fine, because the system can Scale the bitmap regarding the screen density when you finally need to load the bitmap.

This is always true only if BitmapFactory.Options.inScaled = false