# Android - width and height of bitmap without loading it

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to get the width and height of a bitmap but using this gives an out of memory exception:

```
    Resources res=getResources();
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.pic); 
    BitmapDrawable bDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, mBitmap);

    //get the size of the image and  the screen
    int bitmapWidth = bDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = bDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
```

I read the solution at the question [Get bitmap width and height without loading to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681274/get-bitmap-width-and-height-without-loading-to-memory) but what would be the inputStream here?

Comment: since ur image is large to load in memory

Comment: I figured that out too.. Hence the question how to get the metrics WITHOUT loading it in memory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify some `BitmapFactory.Options` as well:

```java
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
```

`bDrawable` will not contain any bitmap byte array. Taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap):

> Setting the inJustDecodeBounds property to true while decoding avoids
> memory allocation, returning null for the bitmap object but setting
> outWidth, outHeight and outMimeType. This technique allows you to read
> the dimensions and type of the image data prior to construction (and
> memory allocation) of the bitmap.

Comment: decodeResource will return null, if options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; So you can omit the assignment `Bitmap bDrawable = BitmapFactory.de`. Also you answer is wrong. you have to get widht and heigh from options

Answer (score 6):

Use this

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

see http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html