# Bitmap height not showing up in LogCat

Tags: android, bitmap, android-logcat

So, I'm working on an app, and I need to get image height. This image is stored on the phone. To do this I use following code:

```
        photoPath = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/WIP/test.jpg";
        Log.i("Debuguo", photoPath);
        Bitmap bitmapWV = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
        Log.i("Debuguo", "Test");
        String info = Float.toString(bitmapWV.getHeight());
        Log.i("Debuguo", info);
```

But the problem is that the height of the bitmap doesn't show up in LogCat. I've set up 2 more debug points to check whether the rest works, I get the `photoPath` string and `"Test"` in the debug window, but no height. I thought something could be wrong with the bitmap itself, so I tried different approach of creating it, but still no changes:

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String src) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(src, options);
    return bitmap;
    }
```

Honestly, this is the first time I've encountered such issue - no errors, debug not showing a thing. I have no idea what have caused it.

Comment: `photoPath = "file://" + ...` + `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` + `bitmapWV.getHeight()` = NPE

Comment: try calling `options.outHeight` before returning the bitmap in your second approach (take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17831915/5052976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "file://" prefix

```
String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/WIP/test.jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
```