# How to get width and height of image in gallery android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I have images in sdcard , i.e a sample png has 701 x 438 size.
the size i want to retrieve in my app before putting in `ImageView`.

How to get this actual size of image in your java code?

I mean width and height which is actual to image.

Comment: [This] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681274/get-bitmap-width-and-height-without-loading-to-memory) can help.

Answer (score 0):

You cab also use `BitmapRegionDecoder` to get actual height and width of image in form of Bitmap.

```
BitmapRegionDecoder  bitmapRegionDecoder = newInstance( pathName, isShareable);
```

Create a `BitmapRegionDecoder` from a file path.

use below methods to get height and width:

```
int getHeight()
```

Returns the original image's height

```
int getWidth()
```

Returns the original image's width