# .NET MAUI Image wrong size for android

Tags: c#, image, maui

I ran into a problem with image sizes. I’m loading an image from a URL and need to stretch it, I found a similar question but it’s only for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470529/net-maui-image-wrong-size)
How to do something like this only for Android?

```cs
public partial Size GetImageSize(string urlImage)
{
    URL url = new URL(urlImage);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(url.OpenConnection().InputStream);
    return new Size(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
}
```

I tried this but I get the error

> Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException: ''

I realized that this is because I'm trying to perform this action in the main thread... but I don't understand how I can do this outside the main thread without losing functionality on iOS

When I receive an image from a URL, I place it in the grid without explicitly defining the height and width because the image can be of different sizes and there is no way to add them so as not to crop, let’s say a square image.
I tried using `AspectFill`, `AspectFit`. In the first case, the image fills the entire width but is cut off in height, which you want to avoid. With `AspectFit`, on the contrary, the picture is small and there is empty space around it.

This is what it looks like now with Fill

[image]

And it needs to be like this

[image]

Comment: This should do what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681340/4965913

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve. Maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: @Julian When I receive an image from a URL, I place it in the grid. I don’t have specific sizes, which is why the image turns out to be either too large and does not fit into the screen, or small and leaves empty space. I need to enlarge the image to fill the entire width of the phone screen, without cropping it

Comment: @Julian Added information to the question

Comment: @KoMa Sounds like you want to use the `Fill` option then. It will stretch the image and maintain the size defined via `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`.

Comment: @Julian I can’t explicitly declare the height and width, because I need the image not to be limited and to display what was loaded into the admin panel - Square, rectangular, thin rectangular. 
And without declaring the height, Fill also crops the image

Comment: @MaximeEsprit Unfortunately it also gives an error

Comment: @KoMa So you basically want to show the real image size? Please explain the use case better. Can you provide a screenshot or mockup of what it is supposed to look like? You may need to add the Image to an unrestrained layout.

Comment: @Julian Added an example

Comment: I still don't fully grasp your requirement. Do the images always have the same aspect ratio? What defines or constrains the width and height for the images in your app? And where do you call the `GetImageSize()` method?

Comment: @Julian The image can have different aspect ratios, there are no obvious restrictions, just to fill the entire available width on the phone screen. I call the method before creating the image, I create all the markup in C#

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the main thread, however, when you know the image has been fully downloaded, you need to call either Invalidate or InvalidateMeasure to ensure that the new dimensions are realized and rendered from.

Comment: @KoMa Do you only receive the link or do you receive some kind of JSON or XML response from an API that contains more information about the image? Many APIs provide meta information instead of only specifying the URL.

Comment: @Julian I'm getting the body from the API. I understand that it is possible to add height and width definitions while uploading the image to the server, but now I want to do without this, because... I don't have access to modify the admin panel for this

Comment: @KoMa Please show where and how you're calling `GetImageSize()`, this will make it easier to propose a solution based on what you already have.

Comment: @KoMa If your error is ```Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException:``` , then you may want to run your code in a background thread. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14443056/4965913. The code BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(url.OpenConnection().InputStream) is a long task because it download data, it can run for seconds. If a long task is executed on the main thread, your UI will not respond to the user until the task is finished, the application will freeze. Android prevent this and throw this error instead of freezing the UI.

Comment: @MaximeEsprit That's for Java. In C# you would rather delegate the work to a thread pool thread using [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run).

Comment: @Julian Off course you're right, the syntax is await Task.Run(() => { /*do work*/ });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not providing a lot of context and code, I'll provide a rather generic approach to this problem.

In order to solve the *Android.OS.NetworkOnMainThreadException* issue, which occurs, because you're running a network or I/O bound operation on the MainThread (e.g. by calling the code from the code-behind of a View or Page), you could delegate the call to `GetImageSize(string urlImage)` to a thread pool thread using [Task.Run()](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) and await the operation asynchronously:

```cs
var newSize = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    return GetImageSize(someUrl);
});

MyImage.WidthRequest = newSize.Width;
MyImage.HeightRequest = newSize.Height;
```

This moves the potentially longer running, blocking network operation to a background thread and waits for that to complete, while your application remains responsive. The image size is then updated as soon as the network operation completes.

Now, it depends on where and how you called `GetImageSize()` before, because this solution requires the method to be called from an asynchronous context.

Generally, I wouldn't recommend using the actual image's width and height values as those might be too large or too small if you always want to display the image using all of the available width of the display. You might want to use relative sizing here. You could calculate the height/width ratio for that.

So, instead of assigning both the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` directly, you could calculate only the `HeightRequest` using the height/width ratio like this:

```cs
MyImage.HeightRequest = MyImage.Width * (newSize.Height/newSize.Width);
```

*Note, that the `Width` (not `WidthRequest`!) property is used above, which is the calculated width based on the rendered layout.*

For this to work, your image should not specify any values for `WidthRequest` or `HeightRequest` in XAML but rather use the `HorizontalOptions="Fill"`, for example:

```xml
<Image
    x:Name="MyImage"
    Source="some_url.png"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
```